# Remove space between horizontal menu bar and horizontal line

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a horizontal menu bar just above a horizontal line using html and css. Below is my code -

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>CSS Horizontal Navigation Bar</title>

<style>

.nav 
   {
    float: right;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #EDF2F8;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #99CCFF; 
    border-top: 1px solid #99CCFF; 
    }

.nav li 
   {
    float: right; 
    }

.nav li a 
   {
    display: block;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-left:10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: small/1.3 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #104E8B;
    border-left: 1px solid #99CCFF; 
    }

.nav li a:hover 
    {
    color: #B03060;
    background-color: #ffffff; 
    }

    hr
   {
   border: 1px solid #BDBDBD;
   }



</style>
</head>

<body>
<ul class="nav">
        <li style="border-right: 1px solid #99CCFF; "><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Our Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
</ul>
<hr width="100%">
</body>
</html>
```

But somehow, there is a space between horizontal line and menu bar, which I want to eliminate. How can I do so?

[ADDED]
One more question, if you see, there is gap at left and right of the horizontal line. Can I remove this gap as well so that it fills the whole page?

Thanks,
Kartic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the margin on the bottom of the `ul`.

#### Update:

Remove margin from the body to get the `hr` to go all the way across the page.

http://jsfiddle.net/EBNZM/1/

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.nav {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Thgaskell, that's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: One more question, if you see, there is gap at left and right of the  horizontal line (<hr>). Can I remove this gap as well so that it fills the whole page?

Comment: Do you use a [page inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector)? If you don't, you should.

Answer (score 0):

It's the user agent style sheet.

For Chrome: `-webkit-margin-after:`

Resolve by setting

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: They answered right after each other, he didn't have time to see someone else had posted

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.nav{
    margin-bottom: 0;
    ...
}
```

[Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/7Y3cL/)

It just removes the menu's bottom margin and removes the distance. Simple :)

Comment: Not the same. It's changed :)

Answer (score 0):

Navbar bottom and horizontal line have to be margin to 0.

```css
.nav{
    margin-bottom: 0;   
} 
    
hr{
    margin: 0; 
}
```